# Why my mining has average so low

Tags: cgminer, miner-configuration, performance

I bought a YellowJacket to mine bitcoins. I'm using my raspberry pi to test it.

My actual configuration is: Raspberry pi using the usb from a laptop. With 1 yellow jacket. Software cgminer 4.9.2

My question is why I get so low speed? 
What I can do to improve my speed ?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you try getting a USB hub?

Comment: No, I'm using connected to my lap top.@NickODell

Comment: If you haven't changed your configuration, isn't this a duplicate of your first question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USB stick ASIC mining devices often fail due to lack of power over the USB port: laptop USB, weak USB hub, weak power supply.

Make sure you use a powered USB hub that others have had success with. Not all powered USB hubs can handle bitcoin mining.

This is especially problematic when running multiple USB sticks, but even a single stick can fail if your USB ports have particularly weak power as is often the case with laptops.